# How to change the Google Sheet reference from sheet A to sheet B which is used in all formulas and charts on other sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a program that generates some raw data. I have a sheet 'A' which has the raw data columns that I've referenced to create charts and tables on 'Summary' sheet.

Now I have re-run the program that generates the raw data and put it in sheet 'B'.

How can I change the reference of sheet 'A' in the 'Summary' sheet to 'B'?

I tried renaming sheet 'A' to 'old_A' and renaming 'B' to 'A' but that didn't work because google automatically changed all the references on 'Summary' to 'old_A'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you were referring to two tabs A & B within a sheet.

- take a copy of the sheet
- rename the raw tab in this copy_sheet to B
- now you have all the formulas in summary pointing to B
- copy this whole of summary tab and paste it directly onto Original Summary tab. since the design/structure is same, the copy-paste shouldn't be of an hindrance.